# Django number of products in basket by product ID

Tags: python, django

trying to count the number of items in my cart by specific product ID but struggling, e.g. 7 apples in basket. I have been trying to use the python count function but currently not working. I tried add the following code to my cart.py file but this didn't work:

```
def count_prod(self, product)
product_id = str(product.id)
  if product_id in self.cart:
      return count(self.cart[product_id])
```

This is my cart.py file

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product


class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        """
        Initialize the cart.
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # save an empty cart in the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Count all items in the cart.
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products from the database.
        """
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        # get the product objects and add them to the cart
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        """
        Add a product to the cart or update its quantity.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                      'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def remove(self, product):
        """
        Remove a product from the cart.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def save(self):
        # update the session cart
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        # mark the session as "modified" to make sure it is saved
        self.session.modified = True

    def clear(self):
        # empty cart
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.session.modified = True

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

Views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                #  quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect(product.category.get_absolute_url())


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                                                                   'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your `self.cart[product_id]` is a dictionary of the form:

```
{'quantity': 5,
 'price': '1.50'}
```

So if you want the number of items, just check the `quantity` key

```
if product_id in self.cart:
    self.cart['product_id']['quantity']
```

Comment: thanks, this is in my cart.py file. How do I reference this method from my template - do I have to use views?

Comment: That's really a separate question, so I can't help with that. It would probably be easier to call the method in the view and pass it to the template.